# What range of values for $q\in[0, 1]$ imply the convergence of $x_{n+1} = 1+qx_n^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

> Let:
>   $$
> x_1  = a\\
> 0<a<1\\
> x_{n+1} = 1+qx_n^2\\
> n\in \Bbb N
> $$
>   For what values of $q\in[0, 1]$ the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent?

I've started with the following. We are given that $a\in(0,1)$, then:
$$
x_1 = a\\
x_2 = 1+qa^2
$$

Obviously since $a<1$:
$$
x_1 < x_2
$$
Suppose $\forall n\in\Bbb N: x_{n+1}>x_n$:
$$
x_{n+1} > x_n \\
x_{n+1}^2 > x_n^2 \\ 
qx_{n+1}^2 > qx_n^2 \\
1+qx_{n+1}^2 > 1+qx_n^2 \\
x_{n+2} > x_{n+1}
$$
The induction shows $x_n$ is monotonically increasing. A monotonic sequence is convergent when it's bounded. Suppose $x_n$ is convergent. Let's try to find the fixed point of the recurrence:
$$
x = 1 + qx^2\\
qx^2 - x + 1 = 0 \\
x = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-4q}}{2q}
$$

For a fixed point to exist (at least in $\Bbb R$) we need:
$$
1-4q \ge 0 \\
q\le {1\over 4}
$$
Or given initial conditions for $q$:
$$
0\le q\le {1\over 4}
$$

However the solution above is missing upper bound for $x_n$ which I was not able to find. What would be the way to finish the problem? (In the answer section $q$ is indeed given in $q\in\left[0, {1\over 4}\right]$, but i still need to justify that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $(x_n)$converges for $0\le q\le \frac{1}{4}$:
    Let $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4q}}{2q}$ be the larger root of the equation $qt^2-t+1=0$. Since $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is the other root, we find that $\alpha \ge 1\ge x_0$. We also find that
  $$
  \alpha \ge x_n \implies \alpha =q\alpha^2 +1\ge qx_n^2 +1=x_{n+1}.
  $$ By induction, we have $\alpha \ge x_n$ for all $n$. Combining with the fact (in the OP) that $(x_n)$ is increasing, there exists
  $$
  l=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n \le \alpha
  $$ by monotone convergence theorem.
- $(x_n)$ diverges (to $\infty$) for $q>\frac{1}{4}$:
   We find that
  $$
  qt^2 -t+1 =q\left(t-\frac{1}{2q}\right)^2+1-\frac{1}{4q}\ge 1-\frac{1}{4q}=c>0.
  $$ This implies
  $$
  x_{n+1} =qx_n^2+1 \ge x_n +c,\quad\forall n.
  $$ Therefore, by induction we have
  $$
  x_n \ge x_0 +nc \stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow \infty.
  $$ Summing up, $(x_n)$ converges if and only if $q\in [0,\frac{1}{4}].$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $0\le q\le1/4$ and let
$$
x^*=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\,q}}{2\,q}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4\,q}}.
$$
$x^*$ is a fixed point and $x^*>1$ (in particular, $a<x^*$.) We have also that
$$
x<1+q\,x^2,\quad 0<x<x^*.
$$
Since $0<a<x^*$, it follows that $0<x_n<x^*$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Sorry but... *why did you post this?*

Comment: @Did It provides un upper bound for the sequence $\{x_n\}$, which the OP "was not able not find". $f(x)=1+q\,x^2$ has no fixed points for $q>1/4$, has one fixed point if $q=1/4$ and two if $0<q<1/4$. In the last case, the smaller ($x^*$ in my answer) one is an atractor, and the sequence of iterated values with $0<x_0<x^*$ is strictly increasing and bounded by $x^*$. Is there something wrong in that argument?